# having trouble using indexed db

Tags: javascript, indexeddb

I've been using indexed db since yesterday, but I haven't solved this problem for over a day.
I tried the codes while looking at the links below, but it didn't work.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/idb/v/3.0.0?activeTab=readme
https://github.com/jakearchibald/idb

```
function(boardNo){
  const dbPromise = openDB(dbName, version)
  const db = await dbPromise;
  return db.transaction(['board'], 'readwrite').objectStore('board').get(boardNo)
}
```

Strangely enough, if I put the number in the get(), the result came out normally.
ex) ...objectStore('board').get(2)

And it worked well when using local variables in a function without using parameters.
ex)

```
function(){
  const dbPromise = openDB(dbName, version)
  const db = await dbPromise;
  const boardNo=2
  return db.transaction(['board'], 'readwrite').objectStore('board').get(boardNo)
}
```

I think it's because my js is not good, but I don't know how to fix it...

Comment: `.get()` returns a promise. I'm not sure why you're having so much difficulty when the github link in your question shows you how to do it. Perhaps the real problem is that you are not familiar with promises

Comment: I thought it was a number, but it was actually sending a string as a parameter. I was using the values extracted from vue route.params, so it was actually natural, but I didn't think of it.